# How to write regex that matches optional groups that can appear only once

Tags: regex

I need to write a regex that matches a string that may contain three groups between colon signs (say letters A, B, and C). Each group may appear in any order or not at all. But if it appears it can appear only once.

For example, these strings should all match:

```
::
:A:
:AB:
:ABC:
:BC:
:CB:
:CBA:
```

But these should not match:

```
:CCC:
:AA:
:ABB:
:ABA:
```

So far I came up with this `^:((?:A|B|C)?)((?:A|B|C)?)((?:A|B|C)?):$` - but it matches the repeated ones (like `:AA:`).

I tried to modify it using negative look-lookarounds: `^:((?:A|B|C)?)(?!\1)((?:A|B|C)?)(?!\2)((?:A|B|C)?):$` - it doesn't match repeating ones, but then it also doesn't match empty or single ones (`::` or `:A:`).

Comment: Maybe just `^:(A|B|C)?(?!\1)(A|B|C)?(?!\2)(A|B|C)?:$`?

Comment: Almost, it's better than mine, but still matches `:ABA:` which it shouldn't.

Comment: You just need to not match `\1` in the second lookahead as well: `^:(A|B|C)?(?!\1)(A|B|C)?(?!\1|\2)(A|B|C)?:$` https://regex101.com/r/VYR2zS/1

Comment: Ok, that seems to work `^:(A|B|C)?(?!\1)(A|B|C)?(?!\1)(?!\2)(A|B|C)?:$` - could you please explain why my original didn't?

Comment: You could also just write out the combinations: `^:(?:A(?:B?C?|C?B?)|B(?:A?C?|C?A?)|C(?:A?B?|B?A?))?:$` https://regex101.com/r/dJ90rO/1

Comment: So, you wanted to also make sure the 1st and 3rd are not identical, of course you need to add `(?!\2)` there. `^:(A|B|C)?(?!\1)(A|B|C)?(?!\2|\1)(A|B|C)?:$` [will do](https://regex101.com/r/hQF4cq/1). Note it won't work in JavaScript regex.

Comment: Also you could try [`^:(?:([ABC])(?![^:]*?\1)){0,3}:$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZP6qeX/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookahead in which you assert that no duplicates exist:

```
^:              # Match a ':' at the start of the string
(?!             # then assert that the succeeding sequence
  [^:]*([^:])   # doesn't have any non-colon character
  [^:]*\1       # repeated twice
)               # 
[ABC]{0,3}      # and that there are only 0 to 3 'A', 'B' or 'C'
:$              # right before another ':' at the end of string.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/h8hPsD/1).

This works in all flavors that support lookahead and scales nicely: new characters can easily be added to the class.

For example, let's say we want to match a valid [JS regex flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags) sequence, which consists of the following letters, in any order without duplicates: `d`, `g`, `i`, `m`, `s`, `u`, `y`. For ease of explanation, let's say `v` doesn't exist, and that the sequence is wrapped in a pair of colons.

Change the class and the quantifier, and *voilà*:

```
^:(?![^:]*([^:])[^:]*\1)[dgimsuy]{0,7}:$
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/h8hPsD/2).

Comment: Given that `[ABC]{0,3}` restricts the characters  between `:` to that set and you cannot have more than one `:` after the first one, it would seem you could simplify this to `^:(?!.*(.).*\1)[ABC]{0,3}:$`

Comment: That would be another way to put it, yes, but I prefer overspecifying to simplifying.