# How to write a regex that captures 3 different groups, which appear in string in any order, but at most once, without any other characters?

Tags: regex

I want a regex, to capture groups in string. Lets call these A, B, C (but these are groups, so not just letters). I want to match strings where these are in the string, nothing else, in any order, 0 or 1 times. It is important to capture these groups!
I have seen the post [How to write regex that matches optional groups that can appear only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76953592/how-to-write-regex-that-matches-optional-groups-that-can-appear-only-once) but I don't know how to capture these A B C groups too.
So I want to match these:

"",
"ABC",
"ACB",
"BAC",
"BCA",
"CAB",
"CBA",
"AB",
"BA",
"AC",
"CA",
"BC",
"CB",
"A",
"B",
"C"

Hope I didn't miss any possibility!

Comment: How do you mean you want to *capture*? However, try e.g. [`^(?:([ABC])(?!.*?\1)){0,3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/zxwd0u/1)

Comment: I mean I want to to have groups for A, B and C, so I can read their values. Also, A B and C are regular exprssions themselves, I just wanted to write a more generalized question.

Comment: You could use this with any substrings/-expressions as well, as long as they don't intersect in what they match, e.g.: [`^(?:(foo|bar|baz)(?!.*?\1)){0,3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/jPUFqC/1)

Comment: I modified what you have given, but as you can see, it still captures repeating patterns ^(?:(?:(foo)|(bar)|(baz))(?!.*?\1)){0,3}$ https://regex101.com/r/icTacZ/1

Comment: Please read about [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). If you use three different capturing groups (like in your sample) it would be [`^(?:(?:(foo)|(bar)|(baz))(?!.*?(?:\1|\2|\3))){0,3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/VTOJ1q/1)